# Why would selecting into a variable and updating a column with a single quote in the name throw an error in PDP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When running the following PHP code:

```
$setUIDs = $this->_dbh->prepare("SET @uids := ''; ");
$setUIDs->execute();

$sth = $this->_t_dbh->prepare($stmt);
$success = $sth->execute(array_merge($values,$where['vals']));

if($success){
    $sth2 = $this->_t_dbh->prepare($stmt2);
    $sth2->execute();
}
```

I receive the following error from PDO:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,`Num`=?,`Percent`=?,`PC`=?,`LinkD 1`=?,`LinkD 2`=?,`LinkD 3`=? WHERE (`sys_id`' at line 1'
```

For reference,

```
$stmt == 'UPDATE t_744 SET `txt'`=?,`Num`=?,`Percent`=?,`PC`=?,`LinkD 1`=?,`LinkD 2`=?,`LinkD 3`=? WHERE (`sys_id` = ?) AND (SELECT @uids := CONCAT_WS(',', @uids, `sys_id`)) IS NOT NULL;'
array_merge($values,$where['vals']) == Array
(
    [0] => b
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => A
    [5] => A
    [6] => 
    [7] => 3
) //blanks are NULL
$stmt2 == 'SELECT TRIM(LEADING ',' FROM @uids) as updated;'
```

When I run this:

```
SET @uids := '';
UPDATE t_744 SET `txt'`='b',`Num`=NULL,`Percent`=NULL,`PC`=NULL,`LinkD 1`='A',`LinkD 2`='A',`LinkD 3`=NULL WHERE (`sys_id` =3) AND (SELECT @uids := CONCAT_WS(',', @uids, `sys_id`)) IS NOT NULL;
SELECT TRIM(LEADING ',' FROM @uids) as updated;
```

directly (in MySQL workbench) it works fine.

If I remove the:

```
AND (SELECT @uids := CONCAT_WS(',', @uids, \`sys_id\`)) IS NOT NULL
```

It works fine.

And if none of the columns have a single quote in them it works fine (double quotes don't break it.)

So it seems to me that the error is a combination of:

- Selecting into the variable in the WHERE clause
- Having a ' in a column
- Preparing with PDO

Banging my head against the wall. Probably missing something obvious at this point. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I suspect that the single quote as part of the column name will need to escaped. Do you have code that automatically adds the backticks around column names? If so that that is where to add the escapes. Basically, you need to parse the SQL identifying column names.

Comment: I tried that. Changing text' to text\' in the example resulted in "unknown column text\'", so it would appear that everything in the backticks is treated as literal (meaning it actually expect the column name to have a \ and ' if I escape the quote).

Comment: Column names with single quotes are perfectly Ok. see this code as a demonstration: [questions/31785723/Col name with quote works](http://pastebin.com/uTTnfC5A). However you mention removing the sub query from the 'where' clause helped. Will try and check that.

Comment: @RyanVincent Yes, thanks. Seems if I have the subquery OR the single quote it works fine. But with both it fails.

Edit: I don't see why those should effect each other though... so I'm still sort of expecting that to be coincidental..

Comment: I should note, the goal here is to run an update, and in the process get a list of `sys_id` (the primary key) for all rows updated. Worst case scenario, we can simply do a separate query before the update (selecting with the same WHERE) to get the ids, but I'd still love to know why this isn't working for the sake of knowing.

Comment: Ah, you are being 'greedy' and trying to avoid a couple of queries? :) Understandable but not very maintainable.  I think i will pass at this point as it is information gained that I would not find useful. The demonstration about the 'single quote' was useful as I learned something new. Hope you sort it out.

Comment: Being greedy indeed. Some of our clients are running updates like this on a few hundred thousand to a couple million records, so any tiny bit of efficiency we can squeeze out makes a big difference. ; ) Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Wasn't criticising - just pointing out that it is work that I have no likely use for.